# Separate Comment Form DIV from Comments DIV

Tags: comments

Is there a way to edit the output of a specific file/line of code that will remove the comment form div from the comments div? Currently, I cannot separate the two to place them next to each other, rather than stacked on one another. It doesn't really work with the theme I'm editing, but cannot find a way to remove it.

Here as a really basic example is how the code looks now:

```
<div id="comments">
    (comments go here)
<div id="comment-form">
    (comment form goes here)
</div></div>
```

But what I need is this:

```
<div id="comments">
    <div id="comment-display">
        (comments go here)</div>
    <div id="comment-form">
        (comment form goes here)</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: have you tried editing the comments.tpl.php file if Drupal 7 or comments.html.twig file if on Drupal 8?

Comment: Seriously, you are a lifesaver. I know I probably should have looked there, but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments of question, edit the html within the comments.tpl.php file of the theme's templates folder.